# greenDAO: compare two properties with each other

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao

I am sure this should be simple but I can't seem to find a solution.

Say I have a table with 5 fields (id, colour, size, scanned, expected)

how do I get all the rows where the expected is greater than then scanned?

I have tried

```
mydao.Property.Expected.gt(mydao.Property.Scanned).list()
```

but this returns 0 rows. Using the LOG_SQL boolean I can see that it is looking for a property field, not the value of the field.

```
D/greenDAO: Values for query: [0, de.greenrobot.dao.Property@33ecce97]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

greenDAO's [QueryBuilder API](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/queries/) does not support that (yet). You have to use a [raw query](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/queries/#Raw_queries).

It will look something like this:

```
Query myQuery = myDao.queryBuilder().where(new StringCondition(
    Property.Expected.columnName + " > " + Property.Scanned.columnName)).build();
```

PS.: I also created a [feature request](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/issues/371) if you want to track this for future greenDAO version.

Comment: Thanks, thought I was going nuts!